# going back to a previous instance of a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I would like to go back to a previous instance of a view controller. I tried the

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but was stuck on the loading screen. I would like to just go back to the previous instance.
Right now it is presenting modally. I have tried:

```
    CameraOverlayVC *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardNewSendCase]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraOverlayVC"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    NSArray *viewControllers = nav.viewControllers;
    NewCaseSummaryVC *rootVC = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers[3]];
   [self.presentingViewController presentViewController:rootVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and it crashed. I also tried:

```
    CameraOverlayVC *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardNewSendCase]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraOverlayVC"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
   [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but it gets stuck on a loading screen.. is there anyway to just go back to the previous instance of a view controller? The view controllers are not connected [I have also tried the unwind segue, I even put break points to see if it hit the method of the unwind segue, but it does not]. I modally presented the view controller, but again if i dismiss this view controller, it gets stuck on the loading screen.

Any suggestions would be amazing! Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by "the loading screen"?

Comment: If you are presenting modally then all you need to do is dismiss the modal view from within the controller and it will go back to the previous view.                   TRY: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it completely wrong. You are making the  CameraOverlayVC *vc as rootViewController of UINavigationController which means this is the root Navigation Controller and all viewcontroller added before will be gone. So when you dismiss this you will get a blank or loading screen.

What you need to do is, say currently is are at x viewController then to present vc modally would be:

```
CameraOverlayVC *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardNewSendCase]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraOverlayVC"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and to dismiss vc use a cancel/close button and on its click event just write:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Let me know if you are expecting something else.